# Perform glm on presence/absence data

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, binary-data, dependent-variable

I have a large presence/absence matrix of genes from different strains of S. aureus. I conducted a PCA and observed differences between my conditions. Now, I would like to find out which genes drive this variation.
My presence/absence matrix comes with genes in columns and observations/samples in rows. I have a grouping variable as class factor, which specifies which samples belong to which group.

```
head(gene.matrix)
```

|  | gene1 | gene2 | gene3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sample1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| sample2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| sample3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

```
> grouping.variable
[1] cond1 cond1 cond2
```

How do I call the GLM now?
I already tried:

```
> glm(gene.matrix ~ grouping.variable, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
Error in eval(family$initialize) : 
  for the 'binomial' family, y must be a vector of 0 and 1's
or a 2 column matrix where col 1 is no. successes and col 2 is no. failures
```

However, when specifying a single gene `(with gene.matrix[,1])` the glm call is working. How can I perform the glm call with multiple dependent variables?

Comment: What is your `grouping.variable` and how does it relate to the matrix of genes?

Comment: Can you write down the mathematical model ("the glm call with multiple dependent variables") that you want to fit?

Comment: the `grouping.variable` was simply created with `grouping.variable = factor(metadata_all_samples$condition)`, so it shows which sample belongs to which group of conditions

Comment: I want to find out which genes are associated with cond2. So I guess the model would be

`gene1 ~ condition`, `gene2 ~ condition`. Or is there a better way? would I need to adjust for multiple testing post-hoc?

Comment: I am with @TrungDung that it is important for you to try to write out the model in terms of math. Right now, this really reads like an `R` implementation question, which is off-topic here. However, I do believe there is a statistics question here that will have an easy software implementation once we clarify the math.

Comment: I want to see associations of gene(s) with conditions, which explain the differences I see in the PCA.  My aim is to see if some genes are more associated with the condition than others .I am aiming at something like what the package `maaslin2` is doing (https://github.com/biobakery/Maaslin2). This package is designed to evaluate associations of microbes (here the dependent variable) with conditions and outputs coefficent and q-values. Because here I have presence/absence data, I guess this package is not suitable.

Comment: when Inspecting variable contributions to the principal components 1 and 2 I still see a huge list of genes. So I want to make a more concise analysis to retrieve genes which explain the variation of strains between different conditions. From my point of view (not a mathematician) I guess that would be a glm call with a post-hoc test like Benjamini-Hochberg?